# before_filter in ApplicationController not called (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, before-filter

I'd like to call a filter before every action of every controller of my rails application.

To achieve this, I've simply used `before_filter` inside my ApplicationController.

However, it doesn't work and my method is never called when I receive a valid request.

Here is the content of my ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :authenticate_with_token

  def authenticate_with_token
      begin
          auth = AuthenticatorService.new
          auth.authenticate params[:email], params[:token], request.method, request.fullpath
          @current_user = auth.user
          return true
      rescue Exception => e
          return false
      end
  end

end
```

Even if before_filter is not supposed to be deprecated in rails 4, I've also tried to use `before_action`, but the result remains the same.

Any solution?

Comment: Make sure all other controllers inherits from the Application Controller:  `OtherController < ApplicationController`
Also make sure it really doesn't get into the function, logging or something

Comment: That was it... I was inheriting from ActionController::Base instead of ApplicationController. Thanks!

Comment: You  can use before_action instead of before_filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//edit: 
grml. i saw you already fixed your problem.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :throw_up
  before_filter {
    raise "hi friend"
  end
  private
    def throw_up
      raise "i need to puke"
   end
end

class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
end
```

if i call the index action - its working perfectly.
it is raising "i need to puke".

please do me a favor: if you write methods called by a filter, they should be private.